# SVN Corrupted, need to move with history

Tags: windows-server-2008, visualsvn-server

We have had a problem with out svn repo, it contains everything so is extremely important.

When we ran a dump we would get the error message

svnadmin: E200002: Serialized hash malformed

This is preventing us from performing a dump and moving our content, it also failed on a svn export.

We have found that one of the revisions is corrupt, is there anyway we can fix or repair a repository as we need to move it.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. I have just repaired corrupted file db/revprops/19. 19 here is the version of the corrupted commit. You can see which commit is corrupted by doing svn log.

This file should look like this:

```
K 10
svn:author
V 5
roman
K 8
svn:date
V 27
2010-06-05T16:53:51.953072Z
K 7
svn:log
V 0

END
```

I had to change this

```
K 6
svn:loo
```

to this:

```
K 7
svn:log
```

(7 here shows the length of the next line)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have backups or mirrors that you can get that revision from?

I actually had that exact error today with a corrupted revision 0 on one of my mirrors that I was able to fix by copying the revprops (the corrupted file) from another mirror.  It went successfully and I had no issues afterward.

This might not be a recommended method for doing this so user beware.  Backups backups backups.

Answer (score 0):

We have managed to fix this by doing a svn dump either side of the corrupted revision then merging the two files together using cat or type depending on what platform you are using then importing this into a new repository.

After doing this i performed a verify and it completed to the end, also all history revision is now visable when before it couldnt get past the corrupted revision file.

Answer (score -1):

After several manual backup/restore operations my repository began to give out the same error. I check last revisions in repository root and detect that one of the files in *db/revs/* directory placed in *db/revprops/* (this files are very different in sizes, so, I quickly notice it)